# Delete button in admin Grid

Tags: adminhtml, magento2.2, php-7

**DeleteButton.php**

```
<?php
namespace Xxx\Faqs\Block\Adminhtml\Faqcat\Edit;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

/**
 * Class DeleteButton
 */
class DeleteButton extends GenericButton implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        $data = [];
        if ($this->getId()) {
            $data = [
                'label' => __('Delete'),
                'class' => 'delete',
                'on_click' => 'deleteConfirm(\''
                    . __('Are you sure you want to delete this Category?')
                    . '\', \'' . $this->getDeleteUrl() . '\')',
                'sort_order' => 20,
            ];
        }
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDeleteUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/delete', ['id' => $this->getId()]);
    }
}
```

**GenericButton.php**

```
<?php
namespace Xxx\Faqs\Block\Adminhtml\Faqcat\Edit;

use Magento\Search\Controller\RegistryConstants;

/**
 * Class GenericButton
 */
class GenericButton
{
    /**
     * Url Builder
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $urlBuilder;

    /**
     * Registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $registry;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->urlBuilder = $context->getUrlBuilder();
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    /**
     * Return the synonyms group Id.
     *
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        $post_id = $this->registry->registry('id');
        return $post_id ? $post_id->getId() : null;
    }

    /**
     * Generate url by route and parameters
     *
     * @param   string $route
     * @param   array $params
     * @return  string
     */
    public function getUrl($route = '', $params = [])
    {
        return $this->urlBuilder->getUrl($route, $params);
    }
}
```

**Delete.php**

```
<?php
namespace Xxx\Faqs\Controller\Adminhtml\Faqcat;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

class Delete extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {

         $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');


        if (!($faq = $this->_objectManager->create("Xxx\Faqs\Model\Faqcat")->load($id))) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Unable to proceed. Please, try again.'));
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/index', array('_current' => true));

        }
        try{
            $faq->delete();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Your FAQ Category has been deleted !'));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Error while trying to delete faq: '));
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/index', array('_current' => true));
        }

        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/index', array('_current' => true));
    }
}
```

But this button not working in admin form in magento2.If any error in my code.

Comment: whats your primary key fieldname of table for this module?

Comment: id is mytable primary key

Comment: do you want to create delete button per row? or mass action?

Comment: i want create delete button in admin form

Comment: @MahalakshmiM check your controller's delete action. Do you get your id in delete action or not?

Answer (score 1):

Replace GenericButton.php file with below content,

```
<?php
namespace Xxx\Faqs\Block\Adminhtml\Faqcat\Edit;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context;
/**
 * Class GenericButton
 */
class GenericButton
{
    /**
     * @var Context
     */
    protected $context;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context
    ) {
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    /**
     * Return Epp ID
     *
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->context->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    }

    /**
     * Generate url by route and parameters
     *
     * @param   string $route
     * @param   array $params
     * @return  string
     */
    public function getUrl($route = '', $params = [])
    {
        return $this->context->getUrlBuilder()->getUrl($route, $params);
    }
}
```

**Delete.php** file,

```
<?php
namespace Xxx\Faqs\Controller\Adminhtml\Faqcat;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

class Delete extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        if ($id) {
            try {
                // init model and delete
                $model = $this->_objectManager->create('OX\ManageFaqs\Model\Faqcat');
                $model->load($id);
                $model->delete();
                // display success message
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Your FAQ Category has been deleted !'));
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // display error message
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
                // go back to edit form
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id' => $id]);
        }

        // display error message
        $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t find a epp to delete.'));
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

Remove **var/generation** folder and check.

Comment: But why we use getId->context  instance of registry

Comment: you can get exact item id using getId method

Comment: it's working perfectly

Comment: issue solved or not for above quesiton? You can close this question.